# Using Linq, how do I check that a booking does not conflict with an existing booking?

Tags: linq

Given that I have a class representing a booking with a start date and an end date, how do i check that a new booking does not clash with one of the existing bookings within the database?

I can do this in SQL, but being new to Linq I am having problems with the || or operator. I can't work out how to do something like (cond1 && cond2) || (cond3 && cond4)

```
public partial class Booking
{
    private int id;
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}

private string DoubleBooked(Booking booking)
{
    var doubles = db.Bookings.Where(p => p.?????? );

    // Code to process double bookings
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You approach many conditions in LINQ the same way you would construct an if statement. In your case the new booking overlaps if there is an old booking, and the new start **or** new end falls between start and end of the old one **or** new start is before old start and new end is after old end:

```
var doubles = db.Bookings
                .Where(p => (booking.EndDate <= p.EndDate && booking.EndDate >= p.StartDate) ||
                            (booking.StartDate >= p.StartDate && booking.StartDate <= p.EndDate) ||
                            (booking.StartDate <= p.StartDate && booking.EndDate >= p.EndDate))
                .ToList();
```

New end is lower than old end and higher than old start or new start is higher than old start and lower than old end.

Let's have a time arrow where there is an old event marked:

-----------------oldStart-----------------------oldEnd----------------->

Overlapping happens in any of the four following scenarios:

1) ----newStart----oldStart----------newEnd--------oldEnd----------------->

2) --------------oldStart----------newStart-------oldEnd-------newEnd----->

3) -------oldStart----newStart----------newEnd---------oldEnd------------->

4) -------newStart----oldStart----------oldEnd---------newEnd------------->

These lines:

```
(booking.EndDate <= p.EndDate && booking.EndDate >= p.StartDate) ||
(booking.StartDate >= p.StartDate && booking.StartDate <= p.EndDate)
```

Cover scenarios 1, 2, and 3.

This line:

```
(booking.StartDate <= p.StartDate && booking.EndDate >= p.EndDate)
```

Covers the last scenario.

EDIT: Since you mentioned you feel more comfortable with SQL syntax linq supports a similar syntax as well. Here's the same solution using linq query syntax:

```
var doubles = from p in Bookings
                where (booking.EndDate < p.EndDate && booking.EndDate > p.StartDate) ||
                    (booking.StartDate > p.StartDate && booking.StartDate < p.EndDate) ||
                    (booking.StartDate <= p.StartDate && booking.EndDate >= p.EndDate)
                select p;
```

Comment: Thanks perfect!...Thats what I had but I somehow had the brackets wrong. The error made me think that linq didn't support the OR operator properly, which I knew must my mistake. Thanks again!

Afyer your edit I was missing the 3rd scenario

Comment: If you feel more comfortable with SQL syntax LINQ supports a sql-like syntax as well. I'm adding a sample to show that.

Comment: Good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
private string DoubleBooked(Booking booking)
{
    var doubles = db.Bookings.Where(p => p.StartDate >= booking.StartDate && p.StartDate <= booking.EndDate);

    // Code to process double bookings
}
```

Comment: No sorry it does not.

booking.StartDate could be greater than p.StartDate and there could still be a double booking if the end date was in the range of an existing booking